# Multiple Poppers on Google Maps show Only Current OnClick

Tags: material-ui

Hello Everybody I am trying to open one popper at the time on click. I am surprised there is not an example of this on the React Material site. Right now I am trying to render multiple markers with their own popper. However, all of poppers are opening onClick here is my code. PS: I will attach a picture below to provide details of my problem.

```
handleClick = (placement, id) => event => {
    const { currentTarget } = event;
    console.log(event)
    this.setState(state => ({
      anchorEl: currentTarget,
      open: state.placement !== placement || !state.open,
      placement,
    }));
  };

render() {
   const { surveyMapEvents } = this.props.MapStore.surveyMap;
   const { position } = this.props.MapStore;
   const { anchorEl, open, placement } = this.state;
return (
<Paper>
  {surveyMapEvents && surveyMapEvents.length ? <div style={{ height: '600px', width: '100%' }}>
    <GoogleMapReact
      options={this.getMapOptions}
      bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: '' }}
      center={position}
      defaultZoom={15}
    >
      {surveyMapEvents.map((item, index) => (
        ( item.theme && 
          <MapMaker 
             aria-describedby={index} 
             key={index} 
             onClick={this.handleClick('top', index)}  
             background={item.theme.background} 
             color={item.theme.color} 
             lat={item.position.lat} 
             lng={item.position.lng}>
            <MapMakerText>{item.initial}</MapMakerText>
            <Popper id={index} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} placement={placement} transition>
              {({ TransitionProps }) => (
                <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
                  <Paper>
                    <DialogTitle>{item.name}</DialogTitle>
                  <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText><BoldText>Address:</BoldText> {item.address}</DialogContentText>
                    <DialogContentText><BoldText>Start at:</BoldText> {item.startTime}</DialogContentText>
                  </DialogContent>
                  <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={this.assign} color="primary">
                      Assign
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={this.delete} color="secondary">
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={this.details} color="default">
                      Details
                    </Button>
                  </DialogActions>
                  </Paper>
                </Fade>
              )}
            </Popper>
          </MapMaker> 

        )
      ))}
    </GoogleMapReact>
  </div> : <Loader />}
</Paper>
)
}
```

Here is a Picture to reflect that I am always getting the same popper no matter on what Marker I click on Goggle Maps. Can anybody give me some example to show only one at time thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice you are taking a param `id` in your `handleClick`, but you are not using it?

You are creating an array of `Popper` component. Each of which depends on the same `state.open` to open and the same `state.anchorEl` to hang around. So whenever you click on a single marker, all of them pops up and you are seeing the last one on top. Every time the last one remains on top, so it feels only one is getting popped up.

What you could do to fix this:
Make `anchorEl`, `open`, `placement` each an array:

```
state = {
  anchorEl: [],
  open: [],
  placement: [],
  // ...
}
```

Now render the Poppers based on those state and the index of the event:

```
<Popper
  id={index}
  key={index}
  open={open[index] || false}           // use index to find out this one's open-closed state, defaults to false
  anchorEl={anchorEl[index] || null}    // use index to find out it's achor, defaults to null
  placement={placement[index] || 'top'} // use index to find out it's placement, defaults to 'top'
  transition
>
...
</Popper>
```

Also make use of the `id` you were sending to `handleClick`:

```
handleClick = (placement, index) => event => {     // i renamed the second param to index
    const { currentTarget } = event
    this.setState(state => ({
      anchorEl: {
        ...state.anchorEl,                         // keep the anchorEl for other indices same
        [index]: currentTarget,                    // only change this one
      },
      open: {
        ...state.open,                             // keep the other popper as they were
        [index]: !state.open[index],               // toggle only this one
      },
      placement: {
        ...state.placement,                        // keep the others same
        [index]: placement,                        // update placement for this one
      },
    }))
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @mehamasum sorry I am a newbie with react in some cases. I was wondering is there is a way to only open one at the time instead of opening multiple when you click multiple? This what I mean: http://recordit.co/KWVrhpMOVd

Comment: Good to hear! :) I was actually updating the answer.